# The logic for p-value

Tags: statistics

Why do you reject the null hypothesis if the p-value for some sample is below the significance level of 5%?

In the below sample, the null hypothesis is that the mean time remains 20 mins after some change
It doesn't seem to make logical sense, if the sample shows mean = 25mins
And the p value is the probability of observing a sample of the same difference of greater 25mins from the mean 20mins
Why do you reject the null hypothesis that the mean is unchanged, if p = 0.03 then 3% of all samples are 25mins or greater leaving 97% samples 25mins or less
So why do you reject the null hypothesis?

[image]

Comment: Can someone explain it to me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you point out in the question, if the mean time *really was* 20 minutes (and your other hypothesis test assumptions hold), you'd only see a sampling with a mean of 25 minutes or more with 3% probability. Since you actually did get a sampling mean of 25 minutes, it is *very unlikely* that you would have randomly sampled data like this if the null hypothesis was true. Therefore, we reject the null hypothesis that the mean is 20 minutes, since the observed data is not well-explained by that hypothesis. It's not impossible to draw a random sample with a mean of 25 minutes when the true underlying distribution mean is 20 minutes, but 97% of the time, you won't. With that information, we'd rather conclude that something is wrong with the null hypothesis, instead of assuming we got a very unlucky sample (as likely as calling 5 coin flips in a row).

The significance level determines how much evidence you need to reject the null hypothesis. The significance level of 0.05 has been used historically, but there's nothing intrinsically "special" about drawing that significance cutoff at 0.05 or 0.06 or 0.1. But as your p-value threshold increases, so too does the probability of Type I errors, which is the likelihood of rejecting the null hypothesis when it is actually true.

Comment: So the p value provides the % of falsifications to the null hypothesis and the % of falsifications caused by random sampling should be > 5% given the null hypothesis is true. So if the % falsifications are less than that by random sampling, the null hypothesis is rejected?

Comment: @StreamlineAstra The p-value is the likelihood the data was generated under the null hypothesis. At a significance level of 0.05, you would wrongly reject the null hypothesis 5% of the time (when it is actually true). If the null hypothesis is true, 95% of the time, your randomly sampled data will result in failing to reject H0.

Comment: thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Much hypothesis testing boils down to pinning a p-value on the data, based on a null hypothesis. Certain hypotheses are allowed to be null hypotheses because they make predictions we can use to falsify them or, if the only predictions are probabilities, at least make them look implausible.

We can't really give the probability of a hypothesis conditional on data; hypotheses always have probability $0$. (For example, $\mu=20$ has probability $0$ because, insofar as $\mu$ is random due to our finite knowledge, it's a continuous variable, with probability $0$ to have any specific value.)

So we settle for the next best thing, the probability of the data being at least as "surprising" as seen, conditional on a hypothesis. The word *surprising* needs explanation. Again, the observed data won't have high probability on the null hypothesis. Instead, the data will deviate from what the hypothesis considers typical, but only by so much. So we compute a "test statistic", then get that statistic's p-value to quantify the surprise. (The role of the null hypothesis is in the conversion of a statistic to a p-value; computing the statistic itself requires no hypothesis.)

As for why we use $p=0.05$, it's arbitrary and something of a historical accident, as is using $0.01$ in medicine or $0.000001$ in particle physics and so on. It comes down to how surprised a community of researchers need to be before they admit a null hypothesis, hitherto favoured due to either its past predictive successes or its being a "default" model, looks unconvincing.